# upload a zip folder of images and then convert them to thumbnails with php

Tags: php, mysql

I've written a code to upload and unzip a zip file of images to a folder. This file is upload2.php, there is also an upload1.php which I use to input the folder name.

I'm trying to add a function wherein the script will also, after unzipping the files and saving them into the target folder, convert them into thumbnails and then ALSO save those thumbnails into another folder.

The script is also INSERTing various data about all the separate files into a mysql database.

Here's the code:

```
<?php // actual code for upload
$dirname = trim($_POST['dirname']);
$taken = trim($_POST['taken']);
$location = trim($_POST['location']);
$subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
$rooturl = "http://example.com/test";
$dateurl = $dirname.'/';
$mainurl = $rooturl.$dateurl;

require_once 'connect.php'; 
$sqlselect = "SELECT * from learning2 WHERE location='test2';";
$result = mysql_query($sqlselect) or die(mysql_error());
$thumbwidth = 100;
$thumbheight = 100;

function makeThumbnail($sourcefile, $endfile, $thumbwidth, $thumbheight, $quality) {
    ini_set( "memory_limit","192M");
// Takes the sourcefile (path/to/image.jpg) and makes a thumbnail from it
// and places it at endfile (path/to/thumb.jpg).
// Load image and get image size.
    if (file_exists($sourcefile)) {

        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourcefile);
        $width = imagesx( $img );
        $height = imagesy( $img );

            if ($width > $height) {

            $newwidth = $thumbwidth;
            $divisor = $width / $thumbwidth;
            $newheight = floor( $height / $divisor);
            } else {

            $newheight = $thumbheight;
            $divisor = $height / $thumbheight;
            $newwidth = floor( $width / $divisor );
            }

        // Create a new temporary image.
        $tmpimg = imagecreatetruecolor( $newwidth, $newheight );

        // Copy and resize old image into new image.
        imagecopyresampled( $tmpimg, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height );

        // Save thumbnail into a file.
        imagejpeg( $tmpimg, $endfile, $quality);

        // release the memory
        imagedestroy($tmpimg);
        imagedestroy($img);
    } else {
    echo "The file " . $sourcefile . " does not exist";
    }  
}
function makeDirectory($dirname) { //This function makes both the directory the photos will be unzipped into, and a directory nested within that for the thumbnails of those photos. 
    mkdir($dirname, 0777);
    mkdir($dirname.'/thumbs', 0777);
    } 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

if (file_exists($dirname) && is_dir($dirname)) { // determines whether or not this particular directory exists
    echo "the directory exists and it is called: " . $mainurl;    
    echo "<br />";     
} else {
    makeDirectory($dirname); 
}

if($_FILES["zip_file"]["name"]) { // pull the name of the zip file from the upload
    $filename = $_FILES["zip_file"]["name"];
    $source = $_FILES["zip_file"]["tmp_name"];
    $type = $_FILES["zip_file"]["type"];
    $name = explode(".", $filename); //format the filename for a variable
    $accepted_types = array('application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed', 'multipart/x-zip', 'application/x-compressed');
    foreach($accepted_types as $mime_type) {
        if($mime_type == $type) {
            $okay = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        $continue = strtolower($name[1]) == 'zip' ? true : false; // let user know if the zip file has not been uploaded
        if(!$continue) {
            $message = "The file you are trying to upload is not a .zip file. Please try again.";
        }
        $target_path = $dirname."/".$name; // get the $target_path variable to for the move_uploaded_file() function.
        if(move_uploaded_file($source, $target_path)) { // this block extracts the zip files and moves them to the $dirname directory

            $zip = new ZipArchive();
            $x = $zip->open($target_path);
            if ($x === true) {
                $zip->extractTo($dirname."/");
                $images = array();
                for ($i=0; $i<$zip->numFiles; $i++) {
                    $images[] = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
                }

                $zip->close();
                unlink($target_path);
            }
        $message = "Your .zip file was uploaded and unpacked.";
}
    } else {       
    $message = "There was a problem with the upload. Please try again.";
}
$newdir = scandir($dirname);
    foreach ($newdir as $key => $value) {
        if ($value!='.' && $value!='..') {
            $thumburl = $rooturl.$dateurl.'thumbs/'.$value;
                echo 'Key: ' . "$key;" . ' Value: ' . "$value" ."<br />\n";
                    $sourcefile = $value;
                    $endfile = 'http://example.com/test/'.$dirname.'/thumbs/'.'$value';
                makeThumbnail($sourcefile, $endfile, $thumbwidth, $thumbheight, $quality);
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO learning3 (taken, location, subject, rooturl, dateurl, imagename, thumburl) VALUES ('$taken', '$location', '$subject', '$rooturl', '$dateurl', '$value', '$thumburl')");
                    echo "<br />";
                    echo '<img src="'.$thumburl.'>< /img>';
                    echo "$value"." inserted successfully!";
                } else {
                    echo $value." not inserted, thumbnail not created.";
                    echo $insert_sql . '<BR>' . mysql_error();
                }
            }
        } else { echo 'Please input your data and select a zip file.';
    }
echo '<html>';    
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR...nsitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
if($message) echo "<p>$message</p>";
if($taken) echo "<p>pictures taken on: " . $taken . "</br>";
if($subject) echo "<p>subject: " . $subject . "</br>";
if($location) echo "<p>location: " . $location . "</br>";
if(($rooturl) && ($dateurl)) echo "<p>directory is called: " . $rooturl.$dateurl. "</br>";
?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload2.php">
         <label for="dirname">Directory to use?: </label> <input name="dirname" size="20" type="text" value="<?php echo $dirname; ?>" /><br />
<label for="taken">When was this taken?:</label> <input name="taken" size="20" type="text" value="<?php echo $dirname; ?>" /><br />
<label for="location">Where was this taken?</label> <input name="location" size="20" type="text" /><br />
<label for="subject">subject?</label> <input name="subject" size="20" type="text" /><br />
<!--< />-->
<input type=hidden name="mainurl" value="<?php echo "http://example.com/test/".'$dirname;' ?>" />
<label>Choose a zip file to upload: <input type="file" name="zip_file" /></label>
<br />
<input type=submit name='submit' value="Upload" /> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The thing I can't figure out about the script is this: it does not create the thumbnails and put them into the new thumbnail folder, although it does create the correct folders, and the mysql inserts are successful. Rather than the thumbnails being saved, I get the simple error messsage "the file does not exist." The thing is, I know the file does exist, because the earlier part of the script creates it.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here, or even give me a hint as to where I should be looking?

Comment: Please consider cutting your example code down to just the image-handling stuff.

Comment: Check the return value of imagejpeg().

Answer (score 1):

So, I tested the `makeThumbnail()` function directly (both with files in the current directory and then with files outside of it) and in both cases, it worked fine. It's kinda hard to know exactly what's going on without being able to fully execute the code, but my guess is that it lies in the call to `makeThumbnail()`. Is it possible that you're forgetting to prepend the path to `$sourcefile` before making the call? Is it possible there are white spaces at the beginning or end of `$sourcefile`? The function works, so it has to be the calling code that's responsible.

Just skimming that code, shouldn't the call be: `makeThumbnail($dirname.$sourcefile[...])` instead of `makeThumbnail($sourcefile[...])` (or `"$dirname/$sourcefile"`, but you get the point)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "prepend the path."